# Trying to print strings to console however I get extra characters and I don't know why

Tags: assembly, console, lc3

I am new to assembly and LC-3. I was introduced to it by my professor for the majority of the work we do for the class. We are supposed to write a code that takes user input and performs a task using subroutines and prints the output to the console. It is able to perform the task successfully, returning the correct output, however, I am having issues with printing to the console. I can't figure out what is going on.

```
        .ORIG x3000
        BR MAIN
WHILE:                      
        ADD R0, R0, R1          
        ADD R2, R2, #-1         
MULTIPLY:                   
        AND R2, R2, R2
        BRp WHILE           
        RET
MAIN:
        AND R1, R0, #0          
        AND R2, R0, #0          
        AND R3, R0, #0

        LD R3, NEGASCII         

        AND R0, R0, #0          
        LEA R0, PROMPT1         
        PUTS                
        GETC                
        OUT             
        ADD R1, R0, R3          
        
        AND R0, R0, #0          
        LEA R0, NL          
        PUTS                

        AND R0, R0, #0          
        LEA R0, PROMPT2         
        PUTS                
        GETC                
        OUT             
        ADD R2, R0, R3          

        AND R0, R0, #0          
        LEA R0, NL          
        PUTS                
        
        AND R0, R0, #0          
        JSR MULTIPLY            
        LD R3, ASCII
        ADD R0, R0, R3
        OUT

        HALT
NL      .FILL xA            
ASCII   .FILL x30           
NEGASCII.FILL xFFD0         
PROMPT1 .STRINGZ "Enter 1st number: "
PROMPT2 .STRINGZ "Enter 2nd number: "
            .END
```

If my inputs are `3 3`
The console should display

```
Enter 1st Number: 3
Enter 2nd Number: 3
9
```

However, instead, it displays

```
Enter 1st Number: 3
0ÐÿEnter 2nd Number: Enter 2nd number: 3
0ÐÿEnter 2nd Number: 9
```

And I can't figure out why.

Comment: Presumably, `PUTS` expects a nul-terminated string. You'll have to add something that emits the value 0 after the `xA`, or just use `.STRINGZ "\n"` if the assembler supports that. Or use `PUTC` if such a function exists.

Answer (score 0):

Using PUTS to print any single ASCII value stored with a .FILL pseudo-op will end up printing the value stored in every register after the address of the .FILL until it reaches a value of x0000 (null character, which would terminate the string) in memory. In order to only print the New Line you would load NL into R0, then use OUT in order to print the ASCII character associated with the value stored in R0.
This:

```
 AND R0, R0, #0          
    LEA R0, NL          
    PUTS
```

Should instead be this:

```
 AND R0, R0, #0          
    LD R0, NL          
    OUT
```

Your program as of right now will also not be capable of printing any outputs greater than 9. Consider that your two digit outputs will in fact need to be composed of two different ASCII characters.